# Custom serialization/deserialization of specific objects

Tags: .net, serialization, json.net

The `JSON`-objects I need to deserialize have the following form:

```
{
   "typeName": 
     {
       "field1": "content1", 
       "field2": "content2" ...
     }
}
```

Basically it means, that every object except of an array is contained in a wrapper object, where the field name is the type of the wrapped object. The type name is needed to create an instance of a specific subclass. I cannot change anything, but need to use this interface. I tried to write a custom converter, but I don't know how to distinguish the type information from a normal field name of the the wrapped object. Is it possible to solve that problem in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but I am assuming that your "typeNames" are not fixed.  If so, you can deserialize into a dictionary using [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/), viz:

```
    public void DeserializeSomeStuff()
    {
        const string json = @"{""typeName"":{""field1"": ""content1"",""field2"": ""content2""}}";
        var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>>(json);
        foreach (var kvp in obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("key={0}", kvp.Key);
            foreach (var kv in kvp.Value)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    key={0} value={1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
            }
        }

        // key=typeName
        //     key=field1 value=content1
        //     key=field2 value=content2
    }
```